# Inequality for local spectral moments of adjacency matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

According to [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.71.056103), the local spectral moments $\mu_k(i)$ are defined as the $i$-th diagonal entry of the $k$-th power of the adjacency matrix $A$ of a simple graph $G = (V, E)$, i.e.,

$$ \mu_k(i) := \left( A^k \right)_{ii}.$$

Later in the [paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.71.056103), the authors state that

$$ \mu_k(i) \leq \lambda^k $$

for every vertex $i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ and for every $k \in \mathbb N$ where $\lambda$ is the main eigenvalue of $A$.

I would like to know where this inequality comes from. I could imagine the Perron-Frobenius theorem playing a role.

Comment: Note that $\sum_k \mu_k(u) = \mu_k = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j^k$, where $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the graph is undirected, its [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) $\bf A$ is symmetric and, thus, has real eigenvalues and a [spectral decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) ${\bf A} = {\bf Q} {\bf \Lambda} {\bf Q}^\top$. Hence,

$$ \mu_k (i) := {\bf e}_i^\top {\bf A}^k {\bf e}_i = {\bf e}_i^\top {\bf Q} {\bf \Lambda}^k {\bf Q}^\top {\bf e}_i \leq \left( \lambda_{\max} ({\bf A}) \right)^k \underbrace{{\bf e}_i^\top {\bf Q} \, {\bf Q}^\top {\bf e}_i}_{= {\bf e}_i^\top {\bf e}_i = 1} = \left( \lambda_{\max} ({\bf A}) \right)^k$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $Q^{-1}$ instead of $Q^T$ like in the Wikipedia article you posted? Why is $(Q \Lambda Q^{-1})^k = Q \Lambda^k Q^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @Bob Since the matrix $\bf Q$ is orthogonal, its inverse is its transpose. Compute the square ($k=2$) and note that $\bf Q^\top Q = I$

Comment: Thank you so much!